# How do you make the "Created" property show up in Content Search Results when querying Lists / Libraries?

Tags: list, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I have a Content Search Web Part (CSWP) and am using it for querying the newly created Survey Lists on my Site. I have done this successfully, but I need to show some metadata as well, one of which is the "Created" date property. I am unable to get this, as whenever I specify it in the Property Mappings of my CSWP it just returns a blank value.

I used PowerShell to check the property and it should have a value:

[image]

I have already tried to make the "Created" managed property searchable in the Search Schema in Central Administration but it still didn't work and does not appear, even after a full crawl.

How do I show the "Created" property for Lists / Libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a workaround and am just using the **LastModifiedTime** instead. I know that it will get updated if the administrators will add further questions or change settings but that will probably be just part of the training to inform them of this I guess, so to avoid modifications after creation.